# WCF 4 Rest Getting IP of Request?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, tcp

Hey, how do you get the IP address of the person making a request in something like the following:

```
    [ServiceContract]    
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]    
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]        
    public partial class UsersService
    {                          
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "PUT")]        
        public User AddNewUser(User newUser)
        {            
            // code goes here including GETTING AN IP??
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Inside AddNewUser use following snippet:

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpointProperty =
  messageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
```

RemoteEndpointMessageProperty instance offers Address and Port properties.

Comment: The problem is that unless something has changed in .Net 4, it is a real pain to get hold of OperationContext when using WebHttpBinding.  I was able to do by creating a MessageInspector, but it requires quit a bit of hoop jumping.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by that. OperationContext has to be available in any WCF call even if it is REST service exposed on WebHttpBinding. I tested it in WCF 4 and it works.

Comment: In .Net 3.5 with WebHttpBinding you could access WebOperationContext, but OperationContext was not available directly.  I'm happy to hear they have fixed that in 4.0.

Comment: Somehow I am getting the server name where I am hosting my service. I want to get client details