# WebOperationContext - Get Request Ip

Tags: wcf, rest

How can i get the request IP in a RESTfull service using WebOperationContext ( not OperationContext).

Thank you.

(if im way off -or this is not the way to go about it please let me know aswell)

**UPDATE:** Here's a link to the proper way to do it (as the answer below recommends):
 [WCF 4 Rest Getting IP of Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589110/wcf-4-rest-getting-ip-of-request)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to know the IP of the *client*, then you can't do it via the `WebOperationContext` (WOC) - you need to get the `RemoteEndpointMessageProperty` from the "normal" `OperationContext`. The only thing the WOC will give you is the `Host` *header from the HTTP request* (via its `IncomingRequest.Headers` property).

Comment: Thanks. Here's a link to what carlos suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589110/wcf-4-rest-getting-ip-of-request